# Am trying to export html labels in highchart to pdf format but its loading lables without html design

Tags: highcharts, export-to-pdf

Am trying to export html labels in highchart to pdf format but its loading lables without html design. code is below

```
 labels:{
         items:[{html:'<table><tr><td><div class="legendSwatch" id="legendHighSwatch"></div></td>   <td valign="bottom"><div class="legendName">High Risk</div> </td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><div class="legendSpace"></div></td></tr><tr> <td><div class="legendSwatch" id="legendMediumSwatch"></div></td><td valign="bottom"><div class="legendName">Medium Risk</div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><div class="legendSpace"></div></td></tr><tr><td><div class="legendSwatch" id="legendLowSwatch"></div></td><td valign="bottom" ><div class="legendName">Low Risk</div></td></tr></table>',style:{left:'50px',top:'230px'}}]
        }
```

Comment: Going to need a lot more to go on besides that. Example jsFiddle or some other site that we can see this "live"?

Comment: Unfortunately, Highcharts doesn't export html, it's SVG exporting module. Also, labels are rendered as plain SVG elements, so don't have  html structure.